# Bootstrap 3.0.3 affix - content isn't in a fixed place and moves over top of other content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a legacy application which is built with Bootstrap 3.0.3. It is not possible for us to update Bootstrap in this case.

That said, I am trying to with with 3.0.3 to use the affix functionality.

I have the following which I've also set up on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x8fc9opm/8/

What I'm trying to do is have a `.col-md-8` (red bordered) left area with a "library" of items in a `.col-md-4` (blue bordered) on the right.

The left area may grow to be very long and I want the blue one to always be visible even if the user scrolls down.

So I've added the following to `.col-md-4`:

```
<div class="col-md-4 tag-container" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">
```

[image]

When I run this, with the `affix` moves to the left and overlaps the red area!

[image]

Why is this? I thought affix was designed to fix the content in place.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, when opening the console it gives the message `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery`. When this is added above the other scripts, affix works as expected.

Also wrap the column that needs to stay fixed. Change:

```
<div class="col-md-4 tag-container" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">
    ...
</div>
```

To:

```
<div class="col-md-4 tag-container">
  <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jquery is included. I've updated the fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/x8fc9opm/7/) to ensure this - there are 3 scripts being included from cdn's - jquery, bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css. Still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try runnung jQuery before the other scripts on the page.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x8fc9opm/8/. It's now switching sides! The blue area moves over top of the red

Comment: This is because there are no styles, there is no way to know where the div needs to be positioned. Check out my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/3t45pjuh/6/ I wrapped the div that needs to scroll, so the position of the parent stays the same. This way the plugin has an idea where to position the element when scrolling.

Comment: So what's the point in the whole `affix` thing in Bootstrap if you're having to add classes and write CSS to do the positioning? All I want is for the blue area to not move as the user scrolls down the page. What you've done there seems to work but I don't understand the role of affix in any of that? It only works if you write CSS to do the job you want anyway?

Comment: Well the CSS was just my thinking, it's not needed per se. I took another look an it looks like it just works without. All you need is the extra html wrapper. Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/3t45pjuh/8/ 

I updated my original anwer to reflect the new solution.

Comment: Thanks. I've sorted it now and was as simple as just putting `<div class="affix">` inside the `.col-md-4`. https://jsfiddle.net/3t45pjuh/12/

Comment: Glad you found a solution that works for you :) Happy coding!